# Edges are not dissolved

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Extruding edges from a plane]

I created a plane and extruded some edges from it on edit mode. As you see the screenshot, I filled the last two edges to make a rectangular donut. Then I selected all inner edges and tried to dissolve them. But some edges were never dissolved.

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that kind of face in Blender. What are you trying to do ultimately ?

Comment: I just wanted to turn my faces to seamless, as scene Object Mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t remove the last two edges. Removing them would leave a face with a hole in it, which Blender doesn’t support. Removing just one of them would leave a face that shares an edge with itself, which Blender also doesn’t support.

Answer (score 2):

A single face cannot have an hole, it should necessary be a closed shape.

I would suggest a different approach :

- Start with a single face
- Inset it (<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Delete the central face

Nice clean topology, no Ngon, no concave face :
[image]

Comment: Now I understand a thing what can't be done. I will try to follow your way. Thanks.